# Ceiling fan w/no light - to fan w/lights & remote cntrl - single switch?

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan, remote-control

We currently have a single switch to a ceiling fan with with no light. We would like to change it to ceiling fan with lights and remote control. Do we need additional switch to control light / fan separately,  or can we just use the single switch and remote control to control the other features of the fan?

Comment: You can do either. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: If the fan/light is designed to run off of one hot wire then all the necessary switching is built right into the device itself.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single switch.  This switch will cut all power to the unit.  The fan and lights can be controlled via the remote control.  Usually there are also pull strings to manually switch the lights and fan.

Answer (score 0):

A ceiling fan can be wired so that a duplex (2 toggles on switch) switch will control the fan and the light separately. Additionally, a remote control device can also be installed separate from the wall switch to control both fan and light.

Most new fans on the market today have a remote included with the fan. There are also remote upgrades available that include the receiving and sending units. The receiver mounts (and is wired) under the ceiling ring.